# React-google-maps/api Cant see heatmap layer

Tags: reactjs, heatmap, react-google-maps-api

react-google-maps/api does not showing HeatMap? In the console i have this error :

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: b.lat is not a function
    at Gjb (visualization_impl.js:11:220)
    at visualization_impl.js:10:39
    at _.Oi.forEach (js?key=AIzaSyCH8QC64KWWWiPKyKnnlTYhT1JgG_2pC9E&v=weekly&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap:363:791)
    at Ejb (visualization_impl.js:10:7)
    at $$.<anonymous> (visualization_impl.js:8:185)
    at _.N (js?key=AIzaSyCH8QC64KWWWiPKyKnnlTYhT1JgG_2pC9E&v=weekly&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap:122:321)
    at tf (js?key=AIzaSyCH8QC64KWWWiPKyKnnlTYhT1JgG_2pC9E&v=weekly&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap:124:320)
    at _.O.bindTo (js?key=AIzaSyCH8QC64KWWWiPKyKnnlTYhT1JgG_2pC9E&v=weekly&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap:310:456)
    at d (visualization_impl.js:12:34)
    at Mjb (visualization_impl.js:13:274)
```

i tried to change opacity , radius ... etc but result was the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.